# When a number is blit on the pygame window when the user presses a numeric key more than once it overwrites. I want a way for it to not overwrite

Tags: python

I am making a Calculator with PyGame and I am making good progress. But When I blit a number which is pressed by the user, it overwrites it. Can anyone tell me how to set a rule like if a character is in the window then when you blit it again you blit it by it's side or away from it.
Here's my code

```
import pygame, math

pygame.init()
screen_width = 1200
screen_height = 500
gameWindow = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Calculator')
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0) 
blue = (0, 0, 255)
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
grey = (128, 128, 128)
font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 40)
fps = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def text_screen(text, color, x, y):
    screen_text = font.render(text, True, color)
    gameWindow.blit(screen_text, [x ,y])

def welcome_screen(run):

    clock.tick(fps) 
    gameWindow.fill(grey)
    while not run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = True
        pygame.display.update()
def gameLoop(run):
     clock.tick(fps)
     gameWindow.fill(grey)
     while not run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                key = pygame.key.name(event.key)
                iter(key)
                if key.isnumeric():
                    text_screen(key, red, 45, 45)
            
        pygame.display.update()
     

if __name__ == "__main__":
    gameLoop(False)
```

Comment: You will have to store the entire number as it is being input and blit the entire updated number to the screen after each key press.

Comment: I did that. But when user presses the key more than once, it blits again in the same place. I want to set a rule that if a integer is in the gamewindow then if the user presses and numeric key, blit it, but a little to the side. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: You don't seem to understand so let's go through this. If a user presses "4" you blit a "4". If the user then presses a "5" you blit "45". You will need the entire number to do math, so messing with one character at a time is pointless.

Comment: It may be notable that you are trying to build a calculator in a game engine. Using something like tkinter, which already has text boxes, buttons, etc.. would likely be a better decision.

Answer (score 0):

You can fill the screen first.

```
def text_screen(text, color, x, y):
    screen_text = font.render(text, True, color)
    gameWindow.fill(grey)

    gameWindow.blit(screen_text, [x, y])
```

Comment: That works but that was not what I want. I want to keep all the numbers and if any new number is going to be blitted, it blit a little on the side.

Comment: You can simply adjust the position.

Comment: pos_x += 45
pos_y += 45
text_screen(key, red, pos_x, pos_y)

Comment: Can you please share the full code?

Answer (score 0):

here is a possibility.

```
def gameLoop(run):
    clock.tick(fps)
    gameWindow.fill(grey)
    pos_x = 45
    pos_y = 45

    while not run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                key = pygame.key.name(event.key)
                iter(key)
                if key.isnumeric():
                    pos_x += 45
                    pos_y += 45
                    text_screen(key, red, pos_x, pos_y)
        pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: I just want this 
1 2 3 4 
I want the first input on a position and then other inputs side by side

Comment: Okay, you can place it by using pos_x and pos_y